# Can backlog value, that is passed to listen() call, be modified later on without closing the listening socket in Winsock2 C++ on Windows?

Tags: c++, sockets, winsock2

First of, I have seen many questions related to backlog but known addresses the mystery whether a backlog value that has been initially set in a `listen()` call can be changed later on without closing the socket (and re-calling the `bind()` & `listen()`)?

What I want to do is to dynamically change the backlog at runtime for my server application. At present, the server had issues with startup due to thundering herd problem (all clients attempt to connect at startup). There are 500 clients. To address this issue I reduced the backlog to 10. This has greatly helped the server to recover from the startup load. However, once the server has recovered I would like to enlarge the underlying queue by modifying the `backlog` value.

So, is there a way to change the `backlog` without closing the socket?

Thing that I saw over the internet, which won't work, is to make a second `listen()` call over the same listening socket by passing a different backlog value. This is clever thinking, however the MSDN clearly states that it will have no effect on the backlog parameter.

Comment: I cannot locate anything on this in Linux documentation for `listen(2)` and `socket(7)`. I do not believe that this is possible. In general there is no harm to setting the largest possible backlog interval, and leaving it there. Perhaps focus your attention on solving the "thundering herd" problem directly, instead of relying on the connection backlog to do it for you?

Comment: Good point - why does it matter if there are 500 clients in the queue? Isn't that actually better than 500 clients retrying over and over to connect? If they're all nicely queued up then you can serve them at your own pace.

Comment: On Windows, you can use [`WSAAccept()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsock2/nf-winsock2-wsaaccept) to throttle your acceptance of connections without having to change your accept loop or manipulate the backlog. Simply provide a callback function that returns `CF_DEFER` when you are not ready to accept a new connection yet.  You could accomplish the same thing with `accept()` by throttling how often you call it.

Comment: Thanks for the comments.
I am afraid solving the thundering herd problem requires revamping the software. Which is not viable.
The side effect of my application server for not handling connections in timely fashion results in a long queue (OS network queue) of client connection requests that actually had expired. When setting to lower backlog value, OS helps by flushing the client requests thus preventing the server to spend time checking & processing. This actually helped. The new requirement by employer is to be able to reset the backlog  value after the server has recovered from startup.

Comment: What you did may have helped the server, but what did it do to the 500 clients? Why can’t the server respond fast enough? When the server is starting, maybe insert a small sleep before each `accept()` call. Tune this value dynamically.

Answer (score 3):

On Linux, you can call `listen()` again to change the backlog. Nginx has the following code:

```
ngx_cycle_t *
ngx_init_cycle(ngx_cycle_t *old_cycle)
{
    if (ngx_open_listening_sockets(cycle) != NGX_OK) {
        goto failed;
    }

    if (!ngx_test_config) {
        ngx_configure_listening_sockets(cycle);
    }
}

ngx_int_t
ngx_open_listening_sockets(ngx_cycle_t *cycle)
{
            if (bind(s, ls[i].sockaddr, ls[i].socklen) == -1) {
                // ...
            }

            if (listen(s, ls[i].backlog) == -1) {
                // ...
            }
}

void
ngx_configure_listening_sockets(ngx_cycle_t *cycle)
{
    // set socket options
    // ...
    
        if (ls[i].listen) {
            /* change backlog via listen() */
            if (listen(ls[i].fd, ls[i].backlog) == -1) {
                ngx_log_error(NGX_LOG_ALERT, cycle->log, ngx_socket_errno,
                              "listen() to %V, backlog %d failed, ignored",
                              &ls[i].addr_text, ls[i].backlog);
            }
        }
}
```

Nginx calls `listen()` again to change the backlog after set some socket options on the listening socket.

I wrote a test program to call `listen()` twice, which succeeded.

Comment: Excellent example! Unfortunate for OP that seems to only work with Linux (and probably other Unices) and now MS-Windows.